# When using a book class (memoir), text shifts from left to right on each page

Tags: margins, memoir, book-design, double-sided

I'm very new to latex, and I've noticed that using a book class causes the text on one page to be on the right and then left on the next and so on. I'd like for it to all to be on the left or centered. How can I change this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Most book classes assume that the final pages will be printed double sided with one side for binding, and their default is to have different page layouts for front (*recto*) vs. back (*verso*) pages.  To fix this you should use the `oneside` option when you load the class.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{memoir}
```