# Page margins are not equal

Tags: margins, geometry

In my latex document the page margins on the right are alterning. What do I have to change to get this problem fixed? And by the way, do you know how I can get the heading ruled`?

```
\documentclass[10.5pt,a4paper,oldfontcommands]{memoir}

\usepackage[polutonikogreek, latin, english, french, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{pst-plot,pstricks}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{natbib} 
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{transparent}
\graphicspath{{img/}}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\def\FunctionF(#1){(#1)^3- 3*(#1)}%

\floatstyle{boxed} 
\restylefloat{figure} 

\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{Abbildungen}

\usepackage[breaklinks=true,colorlinks=true, linkcolor=black,urlcolor=black,citecolor=black, bookmarks=true,bookmarksopenlevel=2]{hyperref}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{total={210mm,297mm},
left=20mm,right=15mm,
bindingoffset=5mm, top=20mm,bottom=20mm}

\OnehalfSpacing

%%% CHAPTER'S STYLE
\chapterstyle{lyhne}

%%% STYLE OF SECTIONS, SUBSECTIONS, AND SUBSUBSECTIONS
\setsecheadstyle{\Large\bfseries\sffamily\raggedright}
\setsubsecheadstyle{\large\bfseries\sffamily\raggedright}
\setsubsubsecheadstyle{\bfseries\sffamily\raggedright}

%%% STYLE OF PAGES NUMBERING
\pagestyle{plain}
\makepagestyle{plain}
\makeevenfoot{plain}{November 2016}{}{\thepage}
\makeoddfoot{plain}{November 2016}{}{\thepage}
\makeevenhead{plain}{Kantonsschule Wettingen}{}{Potz Blitz - Gewitter in Theorie und Praxis}
\makeoddhead{plain}{Kantonsschule Wettingen}{}{Potz Blitz - Gewitter in Theorie und Praxis}
\maxsecnumdepth{subsection} % chapters, sections, and subsections are numbered
\maxtocdepth{subsection} % chapters, sections, and subsections are in the Table of Contents


\bibliographystyle{ksfh_nat} % Sources

%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%
%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%
%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%--BEGIN DOCUMENT%%%--%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%
%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%
%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%
\begin{document}


\section{Thermodynamischer Zustand der Atmosphäre}\label{air}
Der Begriff "Luftpakets" steht in der Meteorologie für ein abgeschlossenes Luftvolumen. Gemeint ist eine atmosphärische Lufteinheit mit gleichen Druck und Temperatureigenschaften.\footnote{\cite[S. 38]{clouds}} Das Modell des Luftpakets vereinfacht die Erklärung der Vertikalbewegung der atmosphärischen Luft und der damit verbundenen Zustandsänderung (engl. Air Parcel "Modell").\footnote{\cite[S. 38]{clouds}}\\
{}\\
Nimmt man an, dass das abgeschlossene Luftvolumen nur aus trockener Luft besteht, kann das Luftpaket durch Zugabe von äusserer Energie expandieren. Ein Energieentzug führt umgekehrt zu einer Komprimierung des Luftvolumens.  Wird der Atmosphäre Energie zugeführt, so erhöht sich deren Gesamtenergie. Dieses Verhalten ist durch den Energieerhaltungssatz ersichtlich (siehe Formel \ref{energie}). \footnote{\cite[S. 32]{clouds}} Die für das Wettergeschehen relevanteste Energiequelle ist die direkte und reflektierte Sonnenstrahlung. 

\subsubsection{Erster Hauptsatz der Thermodynamik}
Die Gesamtenergie des Luftpakets besteht aus der Summe der inneren Energie (U) und der zugeführten Energie in Form von externer Arbeit (W) und Wärme (Q).   Die gesamte Energie eines Luftpakets, ungeachtet ob sie als Wärme (Q) oder als externe Arbeit hinzugeführt wurde, wird als innere Energie (U) bezeichnet (siehe Gleichung \ref{energie}).\footnote{\cite[S. 655]{physin}}

\begin{equation}\label{energie}
\Delta U = \Delta Q + \Delta W 
\end{equation}

\begin{tabular}{lll}
\parbox[t]{4.5cm}{
\begin{itemize}
\item U = innere Energie
\end{itemize}}&
\parbox[t]{4.5cm}
{\begin{itemize}
\item Q = zugeführte Energie
\end{itemize}}
&
\parbox[t]{4.5cm}
{\begin{itemize}
\item W = externe Arbeit
\end{itemize}}
\end{tabular}\\
\vspace{0.5cm}

\label{thermodynamik}\noindent Der erste Hauptsatz der Thermodynamik besagt, dass die Gesamtenergie konstant bleibt. Energie kann weder verbraucht noch neu gebildet werden. Den Sonderfall, bei dem ein Luftpaket externe Arbeit ohne Zugabe von äusserer Energie verrichtet, nennt man adiabatische Zustandsänderung (siehe Gleichung \ref{dia1}, \ref{dia2} und Abschnitt \ref{adiabatische Zustandsänderung}).\footnote{\cite[S. 91]{allgm}} Dies ist nur durch Vernachlässigung der Strahlung und der  atmosphärischen Konvektion möglich.\footnote{\cite[S. 65]{bos}}

\begin{equation}\label{dia1}
\Delta Q = 0
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\label{dia2}
\Delta U = \Delta W
\end{equation}

\newpage

%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%
%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%

\subsection{Emagramm}\label{emagramm}
Den Luftdruck [hPa], die Temperatur der Luft [\si{\celsius}] und das Volumen eines Luftpakets sind die drei essentiellen Grössen, um den Zustand der Atmosphäre zu beschreiben. Die beiden Parameter Luftdruck und  Temperatur reichen bereits aus um das Volumen eines Luftpakets zu erhöhen. Eine Radiosonde, welche mit verschiedensten Messgeräten bestückt ist, dient zur Gewinnung der relevanten Messdaten. Die Radiosonde wird mit einem mit Wasserstoff oder Helium gefüllten Wetterballon in grosse Höhen steigen gelassen. Die mitgetragenen Messinstrumente erfassen in regelmässigen Zeitabständen die Position und verschiedene meteorologische Grössen wie Höhe, Windgeschwindigkeit und Windrichtung, welche von einem Radiosender zeitgleich an die Bodenstation übertragen werden. Durch die gesammelten Daten lässt sich nun ein vertikales Atmosphärenprofil erstellen bis zur Höhe, in der der Wetterballon platzt. In der Schweiz liegt eine solche Radiosondenstation in Payerne. Die Sonde startet zweimal am Tag, um Mitternacht und 12 Uhr UTC, um die erhobenen Messdaten zum atmosphärischen Zustand dem Schweizerischen Meteorologischen Dienst zu übertragen. \end{document}
```

Comment: Add `oneside` to the class options. Note also that `10.5pt` isn't a valid options, see section 1.2 in [the manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/memoir/memman.pdf) for a list of those that are valid (both `10pt` and `11pt` are valid). See e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8489/

Comment: This is not a problem : it is the typographic norm. Inner margins have to be about half outer margins (in two side printing) because when you open a book, you see *two inner* margins  next to each other. As the header rules, load the  `ruled  page style of memoir.

Comment: Are you sure you need all those packages? The `dvips` option to `graphicx` means you're using `latex`, but then `pdfpages` will not work. The `epsfig` package should never be used in new documents.

Comment: I was able to compile the MWE using only ``\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}``
``\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}``
``\usepackage{float}``
``\usepackage{siunitx}``
``\usepackage{epsfig}``

Answer (score 1):

The settings

```
\geometry{total={210mm,297mm},
left=20mm,right=15mm,
bindingoffset=5mm, top=20mm,bottom=20mm}
```

specify an inner margin of 20mm and an outer margin of 15mm. The inner margin is also increased by 5mm due to the `bindingoffset`.

Thus the margins are not equal because you asked for it.

Answer (score 0):

To get the margins to be same on every page put the following right before `\begin{document}`

```
\setlrmarginsandblock{2cm}{2cm}{*} 
\setulmarginsandblock{3cm}{3cm}{*} 
\checkandfixthelayout
```

The first command specifies the margins on the left and right, and the second command specifies the margins on the top and bottom.